# boost ssl client/server shutdown timing

Tags: ssl, boost, timing, shutdown

I have both a boost ssl client and server. Part of my testing is to use the client to send a small test file (~40K) many times to the server, using the pattern socket_connect, async_send, socket_shutdown each time the file is sent. I have noticed on both the client and the server that the ssl_socket.shutdown() call can take upto 10 milliseconds to complete. Is this typical behavior?

The interesting behavior is that the 10 millisecond completion time does not appear until I have executed the connect/send/shutdown pattern about 20 times.

Comment: Interesting. It will be good to see a minimal reproducer so we can tell what factors are at play. It might be an QoI edge case, so let us know more, please.